# C# Deserialize dictionary with complex properties names to JSON string

Tags: c#, json, .net, dictionary

I have the following dictionary, each dictionary key potentially needs to be split by '.' and represented as json object/property/array etc.

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "items.item.id", "1" },
                { "items.item.name", "test" },
                { "items.item.lines[0].id", "1" },
                { "items.item.lines[0].name", "testName" },
                { "items.item.lines[1].id", "2" },
                { "items.item.fixture.id", "fid1" }
            };
```

So the first two entries in the property name are the root item representation, and items that contain [.*] - are array items that could contain their own properties or nested objects. The last entry represents the property name. If we have an entry between root and property items.item.**fixture**.id, we should represent this as the nested object.

I need to deserialize it to JSON and get the following as a result:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "test",
    "lines": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "testName"
        },
        {
            "id": "2"
        }
    ],
    "fixture": {
        "id": "fid1"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do it this way, but stuck

```
public static string DictionaryToJson(Dictionary<string, string> dict, Dictionary<string, string> typesMapping, string mainEntityName = "item")
        {
            JObject jo = new JObject();

            foreach (var pair in dict)
            {
                bool mainPropertyChecked = false;

                string[] array = pair.Key.Split('.');
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    string prop = array[i];
                    if (string.Equals(mainEntityName, prop, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        mainPropertyChecked = true;
                    }

                    if (!mainPropertyChecked)
                        continue;

                    if (prop.EndsWith("]"))
                    {
                        JArray arrayProp = new JArray();
                        // Array item processing
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            
            return jo.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: You'll want to use recursion

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    var origJsonObj = JObject.FromObject(data);
    var jsonObj = new JObject();

    foreach (var prop in origJsonObj.Properties())
    {
        var arr = prop.Name.Replace("items.item.", "").Split('.');
        var name = arr[0];

        if (arr.Length == 1)
        {
            jsonObj.Add(name, prop.Value);
            continue;
        }
    
        if (name.Contains("["))
        {
            name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("["));
            var index = Convert.ToInt16(arr[0].Substring(arr[0].IndexOf("[") + 1).Replace("]", ""));

            if (jsonObj[name] == null) jsonObj[name] = new JArray();

            JObject jo = null;
            while (((JArray)jsonObj[name]).Count() < index + 1)
            {
                jo = new JObject();
                ((JArray)jsonObj[name]).Add(jo);
            }
            jo = (JObject)jsonObj[name].ElementAt(index);
            jo.Add(arr[1], prop.Value);
            continue;
        }
        if (jsonObj[name] == null) jsonObj.Add(new JProperty(name, new JObject()));
        ((JObject)jsonObj[name]).Add(arr[1], prop.Value);
    }
```

result

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "test",
  "lines": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "testName"
    },
    {
      "id": "2"
    }
  ],
  "fixture": {
    "id": "fid1"
  }
}
```